# backbone router # is disappearing from the url

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-routing

This url bellow, load the page:

```
/app/#/rGd4FaNjg22EvTuot3SRKF1suueUSc8Lhd
(I also tried /app/#rGd4FaNjg22EvTuot3SRKF1suueUSc8Lhd )
(and also tried /app#rGd4FaNjg22EvTuot3SRKF1suueUSc8Lhd)
```

...then become

```
/app/rGd4FaNjg22EvTuot3SRKF1suueUSc8Lhd
```

How to keep the # in the url ?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `/app#rGd4FaNjg22EvTuot3SRKF1suueUSc8Lhd`, without the slash after the pound sign. The slash indicates another level in the URL.

Comment: Also with the pound sign directly after the ```/app```?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've started `Backbone.history` with `pushState:true` option. I would guess it looks something like this in your code:

```
Backbone.history.start({ pushState: true, root: '/app' });
```

That `pushState` options removes the `#` for you.

Docs: http://backbonejs.org/#History

So if you don't want your front-end routes be handled as if they are back-end urls, just set `pushState` option to `false`, or remove it because `false` is the default. When it's `false` the backbone routes will be handled with `#`.